# ASP.NET MVC - Check for duplicate in country name without using Model Annotation

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a ViewModel and Repository that are being used by the Controller Action for Create

**Repository**

```
        BackendEntities entity = new BackendEntities();
    public void AddCountry(CountriesViewModel countryModel)
    {
        COUNTRIES2 newCountry = new COUNTRIES2()
        {
            COUNTRY_ID = countryModel.COUNTRY_ID,
            COUNTRY_CODE = countryModel.COUNTRY_CODE,
            COUNTRY_NAME = countryModel.COUNTRY_NAME,
            ACTION_STATUS = countryModel.ACTION_STATUS,
            CREATED_BY = countryModel.CREATED_BY,
            CREATED_DATE = countryModel.CREATED_DATE
        };
        entity.COUNTRIES.Add(newCountry);
        entity.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Then, I call the Repository from the Controller Action for Create. 
**Controller**

```
        public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection, CountriesViewModel countries)
    {
    CountriesRepository countryRepo = new CountriesRepository();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add update logic here
                countryRepo.AddCountry(countries);
                //countryRepo.
                var notif = new UINotificationViewModel()
                {
                    notif_message = "Record saved successfully",
                    notif_type = NotificationType.SUCCESS,
                };
                TempData["notif"] = notif;
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                this.AddNotification("Country cannot be added.<br/> Kindly verify the data.", NotificationType.ERROR);
            }
        }
        return View(countries);
    }
```

> Please how do I Validate for duplicate COUNTRY_NAME using the condition, where ACTION_STATUS is not equal to 2

I don't want to do it from Model or View, but in the Controller or Repository.
Probably putting it before **countryRepo.AddCountry(countries)** in the Controller.

Comment: `bool isDupe = db.COUNTRIES.Any(x => x.COUNTRY_NAME == countries.COUNTRY_NAME && x.ACTION_STATUS != 2);`

Comment: Please do i put it in the Controller or Repository

Comment: You can put it in the controller

Comment: a constraint in db is also a good thing if you want to avoid duplicate.

Comment: The issue is that I don't want to access the database directly from the Controller (e.g. db). That is why I have used ViewModel and Repository. So, how do I integrate it based on what I have. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Method In your Country Repository

```
    public bool IsNameExist(string name, int id)
    {
        var result =entity.COUNTRIES.Any(c => c.COUNTRY_NAME == name && c.ACTION_STATUS != 2 && && c.COUNTRY_ID != id);
        return result;
    }
```

Then In your controller

```
public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection, CountriesViewModel countries)
{
    .......
        if (countryRepo.IsNameExist(countries.COUNTRY_NAME, countries.COUNTRY_ID))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("COUNTRY_NAME", "COUNTRY NAME already exist.");
        }
   ........
}
```

Comment: You are fantastic. Thanks